# Help with Regex on Parameter delimiter

Tags: javascript, regex

I have to match the following text:

```
var html = '<td align="right" width="26%">


            <span class="text2-mbna" style="position:relative; left:10px;"> 
            $0.00</span>

    </td>'
```

I have this regex

```
/<span class="text2-mbna" style="position:relative; left:10px;">(?:\s+)((?:\$)((\d|,)+)\.(\d+))<\/span>/.exec(html)
```

I can actually just replace it in javascript, but I want to know how to NOT capture the dollar($) sign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just move `(?:\$)` before the open paren to its left, giving:

```
/<span class="text2-mbna" style="position:relative; left:10px;">(?:\s+)(?:\$)(((\d|,)+)\.(\d+))<\/span>/
```

You don't need `(?:)` there anyway; it can just be

```
/<span class="text2-mbna" style="position:relative; left:10px;">\s+\$(((\d|,)+)\.(\d+))<\/span>/
```